# VS container window reports mouseover for a mouseenter event, why?

Tags: jquery, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

First, it's not a problem because the code works fine. I'm talking about VS `Containers`.

Code:

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(this).find('span').removeClass('hidden').addClass('show')
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).find('span').removeClass('show').addClass('hidden')
    }
}, '.input .img-preview');
```

When I click on `mouseenter` function, it's

[image: 1]

When I click on `mouseleave` function, it's

[image: 2]

So, I think something went wrong. Then, I've tried with another code:

```
$(document).on('keypress', '.input', function () {

});
```

VS detects it correct:

[image: 3]

My question: what is something wrong? Or is it a VS bug?

**UPDATE:** (based on @Liam's comment)

I've replaced `mouseenter` with `mouseover`, `mouseleave` with `mouseout`. There's a mistake.

HTML code:

```
<div class="main input">
    <img src="~/Content/images/user.png" />
    <div>
        <span contenteditable="true" placeholder="Write you comment..."></span>
        <span>
            <i class="fa fa-camera" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Add image"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-smile-o" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Smiley"></i>
        </span>
        <br />
        <div class="img-preview">
            <span class="hidden" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete image">
                <i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </span>
            <img src="~/Content/images/hamy.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please notice these:

```
data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Add image"
data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Smiley"
data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete image"
```

I've followed [this plug-in](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips) to use tooltip. But it works only with `mouseenter/mouseleave`, not `mouseover/mouseout`. So, if I change `mouseenter` to `mouseover`, it wouldn't work.

That also means: `mouseenter` is **NOT** similar to `mouseover`.

Comment: `mousenter` is just a jquery wrapper for `mouseover` and same for `mouseleave`/`mouseout`. So VS is just detecting the underlying vanilla JS event

Comment: @Liam Before reading your comment, I don't think VS is smart enough to uderstand `mouseenter` is similar to `mouseover`. Many thanks!

Comment: erm...I think it is. It's not *similar* it's the same thing

Comment: Don't change them. They've done this mapping for compatibility. Likely that plugin uses the mapped event names. Basically leave you code as it is, it's fine. The fact that visual studio reports a different object is irrelevant. It's just reporting the actual object not the mapped one. They are identical they just have different names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mouseneter` and `mouseleave` are just thin renamed wrappers for `mouseover` and `mouseout`. If you check the [jQuery source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery) you can see this:

> ```
> // Create mouseenter and mouseleave events
> jQuery.each({
>   mouseenter: "mouseover",
>   mouseleave: "mouseout"
> }, function( orig, fix ) {
>   jQuery.event.special[ orig ] = {
>       setup: function( data ) {
>           jQuery.event.add( this, fix, data && data.selector ? delegate : withinElement, orig );
>       },
>       teardown: function( data ) {
>           jQuery.event.remove( this, fix, data && data.selector ? delegate : withinElement );
>       }
>   };
> });
> ```

so this literally just remaps the (`orig`) `mouseenter`(`jQuery.event.special[ orig ]`) event to a "fix" `mouseover`(`jQuery.event.add( this, fix...`). So they are, for all intents and purposes, identical.

vs is simply following this down the tree `jqueryobject.events.mouseover`. This object structure is created here: `jQuery.event.add( this, "mouseover"...`

`keypress` is "correct" because jQuery has not done this mapping for `keypress`.

Comment: I've tried again and found the difference (in the update). Thank you!